# How to remove Java Web Start from MacOS

Tags: java, java-web-start

is there a way to remove Oracle Java Web Start from MacOS.
I tried running

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```

But the system is still detecting it. Is there a way to uninstall Java Web Start only without removing JDK or JRE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The last comand should be

```
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Java
```